# Can anyone please tell me why the button tag isn't working inside the div?

Tags: html, css

```css
#ss {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#as {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
}

#bd {
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url("use.jpg");
}
```

```html
<body id="bd">

  <div id="ss">

    <button id="as"> Click me </button>

  </div>

</body>
```

the button tag isn't working inside the div, idk why,it works outside the div but not inside it..

Comment: You should also add your html code

Comment: <html>
<head>
 
</head>
<style>
 #ss
  {
   background-color:black;
   width:1500px;
   height:80px;
   overflow-x:0;
   margin-top:-8px;
   margin-left:-200px;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
 #as
  {
   background-color:red;
   width:70px;
   height:40px;
  }
 #bd
  {
   background-color:grey;
   background-image:url("use.jpg");
  }
</style>
<script>
   
</script>
<body id="bd">
 
<div id="ss" >
 <button id="as"> Click me </button>
 
</div>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: Due to improper formatting, your code disapperard from the question. So I didn't see that

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know how to post it.

Comment: Can you tell me why isn't it working?

Comment: check the answer i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is outside the bounds of the page as you added negative x-axis margin to the div

UPDATE:

Margin removed from body.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#ss {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  /*margin-left: -200px; */ // this causes the issue
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#as {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
}

#bd {
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url("use.jpg");
}
```

```html
<body id="bd">

  <div id="ss">

    <button id="as"> Click me </button>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but now there is another problem, the top bar isn't working the way I want it. I mean there is a space between the left side of screen and the bar. I want to set it to full width.

Comment: add `margin: 0` to body

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks again.